# Reactivity lost when variable is used in function

Tags: vuejs3, vue-reactivity

I have a simple Vue 3 app with Vite that calls a Google sheets for data. I am missing something about reactivity in Vue 3. The following works fine

```
<template>
  <div v-if="ssData">{{ ssData.values[0][2] }}</div>
</template>

<script setup>
// Fetch the SS data
  const { data: ssData } = useFetch(ssURL);
</script>
```

The template updates with the data once fetch completes.
But I want the user to retrieve data on button click:

```
<template>
  <h1>Senior Options</h1>

  <button @click="getSSValues">Get Data</button>

  <div v-if="ssData">{{ ssData.values[0][2] }}</div>
</template>

<script setup>
let ssData = ref(null);

 const getSSValues = () => {
    // eslint-disable-next-line no-unused-vars
    const { data } = useFetch(ssURL);
    ssData.value = data;

  };
</script>
```

This does not update the template when data is retrieved. I looked in Vue Devtools and I see the `ssData` object has data in it, so I am assuming I must be doing something wrong in terms of my understanding of reactivity.

How does one use a reactive variable from within a function so reactivity is maintained and template gets updated?

Answer (score 1):

Try to move `useFetch` to the `script` tag and then run `execute` in `getSSValues` function.

```js
<template>
  <h1>Senior Options</h1>
  <button @click="getSSValues">Get Data</button>
  <div v-if="ssData">{{ ssData.values[0][2] }}</div>
</template>

<script setup>
 const { data: ssData, execute } = useFetch(ssURL, { immediate: false });

 const getSSValues = () => {
    execute()
  };
</script>
```

To debug it further you can also try to display `ssData.values` in `pre` tag without array notation in template tag.

```html
<template>
  <h1>Senior Options</h1>
  <button @click="getSSValues">Get Data</button>
  <pre v-if="ssData">
    {{ ssData.values }}
   </pre>
</template>
```

Comment: Sorry I dont follow the use of immediate in the parameters and the use of execute(). I looked on MDN I see no entry for it. Can you elaborate. right now usefetch is a module and I want to keep it that way.

Comment: @Alan [This](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=njsGVmcWviY) might explain it

Comment: @Alan as per the doc (I guess you use Nuxt) `useFetch is a composable meant to be called directly in a setup function, plugin, or route middleware` (link : https://nuxt.com/docs/api/composables/use-fetch)